# Cygwin svn and sqlite: "Disk I/O Error"

Tags: svn, sqlite, cygwin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cygwin svn: E200030: sqlite: disk I/O error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007024/cygwin-svn-e200030-sqlite-disk-i-o-error)

In Cygwin on my Win7 machine with an SSD, svn frequently fails to completely update or checkin.  It prints

`sqlite: disk I/O error`

for a subset of the target directories.

(This is the same symptom as in
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007024/cygwin-svn-e200030-sqlite-disk-i-o-error), but I do not have TortoiseSVN installed, nor am I running antivirus.)

The problem apparently can be fixed by downgrading sqlite from 3.7.12 to 3.7.3 through Cygwin's setup.exe, but I am unable to do that.  When I try it, svn gives me

`SQLite compiled for 3.7.12 but running with 3.7.3` .

I have tried Uninstalling svn and sqlite through setup.exe, then Installing SQLite 3.7.3 and both the Prev and Curr flavors of subversion, with the same result.

**How do I get svn running with a working version of SQLite?**

Comment: Why do you run SVN under Cygwin anyway? Any specific reason?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11007024/220155

Comment: Ack. No it isn't, I missed that bit of the question. Sorry!

Comment: bahrep: Because I need to be in Windows for testing purposes, but do all my development work in a Linux-like environment otherwise (bash, vim, svn, scripts, etc.)